# How to pad the integer withe preceeding 0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, formatting, nsnumberformatter

I am having an integer value like 6 or 65 . If the value is single digit I want to display it like 06 and if it is 65 then as it is ( 65 only ) . I have searched into the NSNumberFormatter class of iphone but not getting what to do exactly .  Can any one help me in this ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use %02d format specifier, e.g.

```
NSLog(@"%02d", number);
```

That will output integer number with at least 2 characters length and output  will be padded with leading zeroes if required

Comment: I'm trying to find the correct similar way when you have a NSInteger/NSUInteger. I usually go with [NSNumber numberWithInteger:myInteger] for integers, then print with @"%@", but then there's no way of specifying width.

Comment: @Jonny, with NS(U)Integer you can use exactly the same format specifier as in practice that's the same plain int (or unsigned int). There's no reason to use NSNumber here just to get a string representation

Comment: Ok. I found somewhere in Apple's docs that they recommend casting NSIntegers to long, then using %ld (if I remember correctly). I used %02ld to get width 2 etc. So yes I don't use NSNumber anymore.

Answer (score 2):

For using the format specifiers as Vladimir suggested, you can also use the [`stringWithFormat`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) convenience method on `NSString` to generate a string from a numeric value in the desired format.

Comment: Thanks ShaggyFrog for adding the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, although I think Vladimir's is prob the most clean. :)

```
NSLog(@"%@%d", number<10?@"0":@"", number);
```

Comment: I am a fan of the ternary operator but in this case, no. You are reinventing the wheel here.